# javascript, why the second text line couldn't replace from first line while the video is playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want subtitle to display 2 lines on video which it mean first subtitle line will move to second line as the first texts appear on first line. Somehow it doesn't work because first and second line print the same subtitles. The function that responsible for displaying texts is $("#video").bind('timeupdate',function(){});
"text" variable should display first line and "second" variable should display second line that been replace from first text. My website example can be seen on [a link](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~rskics/study/caption2/test.html) (work on firefox). The subtitle on top of video is "second" and subtitle at bottom of video is "text". Please help and don't mind the location of subtitle, I will fix it after the function is working correct.

here my HTML5/javascript coding examples,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 included Javascript....</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test" charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <style>
            .container{position:relative;}
            .container video {
                position:absolute;
                z-index:-1;
            }
            .subtitle2 {
                position:absolute;
                width:640px;
                top:400;
                left:120;
                z-index:2000;
                color:white;
                text-shadow:black 2px 2px 6px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:150%;
            }

            .second {
                position:absolute;
                z-index:2000;
                color:white;
                text-shadow:black 2px 2px 6px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:150%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                var subtitleArray = new Array(); //stored all values from XML caption file
                    var tempText = "";

                function loadXMLDoc(dname)
                {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
                    xhttp.send();

                    return xhttp.responseXML;
                }

                function getCaption()
                {
                    //alert("get caption 2");

                    var tempArray = new Array();
                    var c = document.getElementById('container');

                    captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
                    x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

                    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                    {
                        var tempArray = new Array();
                        tempArray[0] = x[i].getAttribute('start'); // get start time
                        tempArray[1] = x[i].getAttribute('dur'); // get duration time
                        tempArray[2] = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // get text

                        subtitleArray[i] = tempArray; //put all 3 values in array


                    }

                    //c.innerHTML = subtitleArray[0][2];

                }

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    //alert("get caption 1");
                    getCaption();

                    var subtitle2 = document.getElementById('subtitle2');

                    var video = document.getElementById('video');

                    $("#video").bind('play',function(){
                        /*
                        setInterval(function(){

                            //timer.innerHTML = $('#video')[0].currentTime;

                            var text = "", cap = "";

                            for( var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                            {
                                //alert("looping");
                                //var currentTime = video.currentTime();
                                var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                                var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);

                                cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                                if (video.currentTime >= cueStart && video.currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                                   text = cap;   
                                }
                                //var t = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = text;
                                $( "#second" ).html( prevLineText );
                                console.log( prevLineText );
                                subtitle.innerHTML = text;
                                prevLineText = text;
                                console.log( prevLineText +"\n");
                            }
                        },1);*/
                    });

                    $("#video").bind('timeupdate',function(){
                        //timer2.innerHTML = $('#video')[0].currentTime;

                        var text = "", cap = "";

                            for( var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                            {
                                //alert("looping");
                                //var currentTime = video.currentTime();
                                var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                                var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);

                                cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                                if (video.currentTime >= cueStart && video.currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                                   text = cap;   
                                }


                                if ( text != tempText && text != "" ) {
                                console.log( text );
                                console.log(tempText);
                                    $("#second").html(text);
                                }

                                subtitle2.innerHTML = text;
                                tempText = text;
                                console.log( tempText );

                            }
                    });
                });

            //window.onload = load;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container" class="container">

                <video id="video" width="930" height="492" controls>
                    <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="caption.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
                    <source src="caption.webm" type="video/webm" />
                </video> 
                <div id= "subtitle2" class="subtitle2">
                </div>
                <div id="second" class="second">
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, here a code,

```
var tempText = "", prevText="";

$("#video").bind('timeupdate',function(){


                        var text = "", cap = "";

                            for( var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                            {

                                var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                                var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);

                                cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                                if (video.currentTime >= cueStart && video.currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                                   text = cap;   
                                }

                                if (tempText != text && text != "") {

                                    prevText = tempText;
                                    $("#second").html(prevText);
                                }

                                subtitle.innerHTML = text;

                                if ( text != "" ) {
                                    tempText = text;
                                }


                            }
                    });
```